# My api project is not hitting my breakpoints

Tags: api, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

.Net Core 3.1 Api

I ported my .net framework app to .net core3.1 and now this...

[image]

Comment: Make sure that your configuration is on Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

@Arsalan is correct, I had my config in Release mode... Thanks!